# Get value from a class member being a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

Given the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CRectangle {

  public:
    int *width, *height;
    CRectangle (int,int);
    ~CRectangle ();
    int area () {return (*width * *height);}
};

CRectangle::CRectangle (int a, int b) {
  width = new int;
  height = new int;
  *width = a;
  *height = b;
}

CRectangle::~CRectangle () {
  delete width;
  delete height;
}

int main () {
  CRectangle rect (3,4), rectb (5,6);
  cout << "rect area: " << rect.area() << endl;
  cout << "rectb area: " << rectb.area() << endl;

  CRectangle * p = new CRectangle(10,10);

  cout << "rect area: " << p->*height << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

how can I get last `cout` statement to work?

Comment: Any particular reason you're using pointer members?

Comment: lost the race to that answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move the dereference operator.  `p->height` refers to the integer pointer `height`. And then putting the `*` in front of that dereferences the int pointer.

```
cout << "rect area: " << *p->height << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << "rect area: " << *(p->height) << endl;
```