# Get value from a class member being a pointer, that is a property of a class

Tags: c++

to illustrate my problem I'm borrowing code from here: [Get value from a class member being a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988489/get-value-from-a-class-member-being-a-pointer)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CRectangle {

  public:
    int width, height;
    CRectangle (int,int);
    ~CRectangle ();
    int area () {return (width * height);}
};

CRectangle::CRectangle (int a, int b) {
  width = new int;
  height = new int;
  width = a;
  height = b;
}

CRectangle::~CRectangle () {
}

class Paper_class{
   paper(Rectangle rect);
   ~paper();
   Rectangle * rectangle1;
}

Paper_class::paper(Rectangle rect){
   rectangle1 = &rect;
}

Paper_class::~paper(){
   delete rectangle1;
}

int main () {


  vector<Paper_class> vec;
  vec.push(Paper_class(new CRectangle(10,10)))
  vec.push(Paper_class(new CRectangle(20,20)))
  vec.push(Paper_class(new CRectangle(30,30)))

  cout << "rect area: " << *vec[1]->rect1.height << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

This line from code does not access the value:

```
cout << "rect area: " << *vec[1].rect1->height << endl;
```

How can I see the height stored in vec[1] ? (it should be 20)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you meant:

```
class Paper_class{
   Paper_class(Rectangle rect);
   ~Paper_class();
   Rectangle * rectangle1;
}

Paper_class::Paper_class(Rectangle rect){
   rectangle1 = &rect;
}

Paper_class::~Paper_class(){
   delete rectangle1;
}
```

Use

```
cout << "rect area: " << vec[1].rectangle1->height << endl;
```

`vec[1]` evaluates to a `Paper_class&`.

`vec[1].rectangle1` evaluates to a `Rectangle*`.

`vec[1].rectangle1->height` evaluates to a `double`.

**Caution**

Your code is going to lead to undefined behavior due to lack of a property copy constructor and copy assignment operator in `Paper_Class`. Please see [The Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) for details.